# javascript split string by KEY WORDS and don't split if enclosed in parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have following input string: `KEY WORD => AND / OR`

```
let query = `(Application = http AND "Server Port" "Not In" 80,443,8080) 
              AND "Client Port" Between 22,33 
              OR ("File Size" In 220,400,500 AND "File Size" "Not In" 5,10,60)
              OR "Client IP" != 1.0.2.1 
              OR Application = skype`;

//I want split the above string into following format

[
  '(Application = http AND "Server Port" "Not In" 80,443,8080)', 
  'AND',
  '"Client Port" Between 22,33',
  'OR'
  '("File Size" In 220,400,500 AND "File Size" "Not In" 5,10,60)'
  'OR'
  '"Client IP" != 1.0.2.1'
  'OR',
  'Application = skype'
]
```

I have the following code that either split the by key words or if string is completely enclosed in parentheses.

```
 query.split(/AND|OR/g); //Split based on key words

************
 var str = '((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25)) OR (Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) OR (Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) AND (Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)';

 var final = str.replace(/\((?!\()/g,"['")        //replace ( with [' if it's not preceded with (
           .replace(/\(/g,"[")               //replace ( with [
           .replace(/\)/g,"']")              //replace ) with '] 
           .replace(/\sAND\s/g,"','AND','")  //replace AND with ','AND','
           .replace(/\sOR\s/g,"','OR','")    //replace OR with ','OR','
           .replace(/'\[/g,"[")              //replace '[ with [
           .replace(/\]'/g,"]")              //replace ]' with ]
           .replace(/"/g,"\\\"")             //escape double quotes
           .replace(/'/g,"\"");              //replace ' with "
console.log(JSON.parse("["+final+"]"))
```

Any help to split the string ignoring the parentheses? Basically I want to extract anything (+KEY WORDS) including parentheses.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse a context-free language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
query.split(/(AND|OR)(?![^(]*\))/);
```

This will only match an `AND` or an `OR` if there is not a `)` following it that is not preceded by a `(`. This is done via "negative look ahead": `(?!   )`.

With some trimming of spaces (`\s*`) you get this:

```js
var str = '((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25)) OR (Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) OR (Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) AND (Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)';

 var result = str.split(/\s*(AND|OR)\s*(?![^(]*\))/);
 
 console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Limitation and Alternative

As noted in comments, the above solution is not suited for expressions with multiple nested pairs of parentheses. The above code outputs a split in the first part of the expression that actually should not happen. As JavaScript does not support *recursive* regex patterns, you'd have to code it with keeping a nesting level:

```js
var str = '((Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25) AND (Application = smtp AND "Server Port" != 25)) OR (Application = pop3 AND "Server Port" != 110) OR (Application = imap AND "Server Port" != 143) AND (Application = imap OR "Server Port" != 143)';

var result = str.split(/(\(|\)|\s*AND\s*|\s*OR\s*)/).reduce( (acc, s) => {
    if (s.length) {
        if (acc.level += s === ')' ? 1 : s === '(' ? -1 : 0) {
            acc.buf.push(s);
        } else {
            acc.out.push(acc.buf.join('') + s);
            acc.buf = [];
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, { level: 0, buf: [], out: [] } ).out;
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This results in extra parenthesis & confusing splitting if there is more than one layer of nesting: `("Server Port" == 1 AND (Application = smtp AND ("Server Port" != 25 AND "Server Port" != 22)))`

Comment: @Gerrit0, Correct. I added an alternative for such nested cases, which cannot be dealt with in one regex (at least not in JS).